# Alternating group is $(2,3)$ generated ? True/False

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, numerical-methods

We know that alternating group of degree $5$, $A_{5}$ can be generated by two elements, one having order two and other order three.

The generators are,
$a = (1, 2)(3, 4)$ and $b = (1, 3, 5) $

Can we do it for higher degree Alternating groups (I am mainly interested for $n\geq5$). I mean given $A_{n}$ can we find $a,b\in A_{n}$ such that $o(a)=2$ and $o(b)=3$ and $a, b $ generates the whole group.

In case the answer to above question is TRUE, Is is possible to write a algorithm to find the generators given the value of $n$.

Comment: The answer is no for $n=6,7,8$. By choosing random elements of order $2$ and $3$ I found quickly  that it is true for $n=9,10,11,12$, and I am confident that it is true and not hard to prove for $n \ge 9$. It is known that for sufficiently large $n$ (I think around $200$) $A_n$ is generated by $x$ and $y$ with $x^2=y^3=(xy)^7=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Every simple group can be generated by $2$ elements. This is absolutely non-trivial and, as far as I am aware, it requires the classification.

About the order of the elements, for most groups choosing one of order $2$ and one of order $3$ works. See

> M. W. Liebeck and A. Shalev, ‘Classical groups, probabilistic methods,
>   and the (2, 3)- generation problem’, Ann. Math. (2) 144 (1996),
>   77–125.

About the algorithm, for the general case I have seen many "probabilistic" generations who just pick two random elements, which seems to work just fine; see

> Guralnick, Robert, Kantor, William, Probalistic generation of finite
>   simple groups, http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.2000.8357

I am not sure if there is a an algorithm in the particular case of $A_n$.

As the size of the group grows, the probability of two random elements generating the whole group tends to one.

Comment: @Are you sure, every simple group group can be generated by $2$ elements. Kindly correct me if I am wrong but few days back I read in some paper that $PSp_{4}(q)$ is not generated  by $2 $ elements.

Comment: I don't think the question is whether the alternating group can be generated by two elements and that's it, but rather whether it can be generated by two elements *with very specific orders* About the order $\;3\;$ I know it enters in a group of generators, but about two I'm not sure

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you, I was editing the answer after realizing what you pointed out

Comment: @Sri Yes. Every finite simple group can be generated by two elements.